# XPath: Translate into lowercase and simultaneously Normalize-space

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm using Selenium with Firefox for Selenium. I want to match an Element on a page containing a certain Text; and so I need the driver to recognize the text on the page in lower-case characters, so it matches with my string keyword `searchkey.lower()`.

I've attempted  to use the `translate()` function in XPath, but I simultaneously want to `normalize-space()` to get rid of any whitespace problems.

Can these two functions be combined into one XPath string?

I tried the XPath below, and some other variants, but wasn't able to make a match with Selenium's `driver.find_element_by_xpath(my_xpath)`:

> `my_xpath = "//a[contains(translate(normalize-space(.), '%s', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]" % searchkey.lower()"`

NB: the same code written in a one-line code block:

```
my_xpath = "//a[contains(translate(normalize-space(.), '%s', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]" % searchkey.lower()"
```

---

#### Further explanation:

For testing purposes, we can pretend that `searchkey = "MY STRING"`, and that `searchkey.lower()` would return `"my string"`.

And the Element on the page that I want to match, might contain the Text `" mY sTrinG "`. And so I want XPath to translate the characters to lowercase *and* remove excess whitespaces of any kind, therefore matching with the above `"my string"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your though process is correct but the xpath has a minor issue. You won't pass expected text to the translate function, you will pass it to the contains function, so it can test if it is there or not

```
my_xpath = "//a[contains(translate(normalize-space(.), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '%s')]" % searchkey.lower()"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put an **extra space after Z** in **'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<"space">'**.

complete xpath="//a[translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<**"space"**>','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'look']"

xpath using contains = "//a[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<**"space"**>','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') , 'look')]"

your xpath = "//a[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ<**"space"**>', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '%s')]" % searchkey.lower()"